# Calculating the Hash of a file using CryptCATAdminCalcHashFromFileHandle in vb

Tags: windows, vb.net, winapi, code-signing, sha1

I am following the code for Checking the Digital Signature of a file at [Sysinternals](http://forum.sysinternals.com/discuss-howto-verify-digital-signature-of-a-file_topic19404_page2.html)

There I need to get the hash value of a file. for that part I'm using the following code.

```
        'Open file
        Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 8)


        'Get the size we need for our hash.
        Dim fileHandle As IntPtr = fs.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle()
        Dim hashSize As Integer
        Dim hash As Byte() = New Byte(256) {}

        Dim b As Boolean = CryptCATAdminCalcHashFromFileHandle(fileHandle, hashSize, Nothing, 0)

        'check results
        System.Console.WriteLine(fileHandle)
        System.Console.WriteLine(hashSize)
        System.Console.WriteLine(hash)
        System.Console.WriteLine(b)
```

Using wintrust.dll as follows

```
    <DllImport("Wintrust.dll", PreserveSig:=True, SetLastError:=False)> _
    Private Shared Function CryptCATAdminCalcHashFromFileHandle(ByRef fileHandle As IntPtr, ByVal hash As IntPtr, ByVal hashSize As Byte(), ByVal dwFlags As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function
```

Output for file handle gets different values in different executions (Which is ok)
But the hashsize, and hash are always zero. and b is always false.

Am I missing something here.
Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration should be something like:

```
<DllImport("Wintrust.dll", PreserveSig:=True, SetLastError:=False)> _
Private Shared Function CryptCATAdminCalcHashFromFileHandle(ByVal fileHandle As IntPtr, ByRef hashSize As Integer, ByVal hash As Byte(), ByVal dwFlags As Integer) As Boolean
End Function
```

You need to initialize `hashSize` to the size of your buffer, and pass the buffer to the function:

```
hashSize = 256
Dim b As Boolean = CryptCATAdminCalcHashFromFileHandle(fileHandle, hashSize, hash, 0)
```

`hashSize` should be updated to contain the actual hash size when the function completes.

(My VB is very rusty, so apologies for any typos.)

Comment: Your VB still has pollish, as this appears correct =P. Excellent.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. I was struggling with this for hours. Never thought of changing the ByRef to ByVal for fileHandle. Thanks a lot again arx.